# Unable to write to Mongo Replica set remotely

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have a 3 full instance Mongo replica set, setup on 3 separate AWS EC2 Linux instances (all same availability zone but different subnets). I can read and write fine to the replica set from another EC2 box in the same availability zone, however, from remote machines (my local box), I am only able to read. Trying to insert or findandmodify returns an error "Unable to connect to a member of the replica set matching the read preference Primary".

If I change my connection string to only connect to primary, then the write goes through fine, but obviously does not replicate to the other boxes.

I tried allowing all traffic between my local box and the three Mongo boxes, but there was no change. I also read that it might be an issue with resolving the dns for the other boxes, so I added host entries, but this did not help either. I can ping all 3 boxes fine when I open up all traffic.

Is there any other configurations required between the driver and the replica boxes?

I am using the c# Mongo 1.8.1 driver. My connection string look like

```
mongodb://mongobox1,mongobox2,mongobox3/dbname?replicaSet=replicasetname&readpreference=primaryPreferred
```

**UPDATE:**

I also found that the sometimes (not sure the conditions), when I take down the master, I can then write fine from local and when I bring the machine back up it syncs properly. But as soon as I bring the machine back up, I can no longer write from local.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I am gonna say this is a configuration error not a setup error, I would say there might be an oddity with your firewall, what is the read preference of your app?

Comment: Its set in the connection string as primaryPreferred. If its something to do with firewall or connection, why does it write fine against the master when set as a single node?

Comment: Hmmm that does confuse me but if you set it to primary only do you get read errors as well? I wonder if this is something with the c# driver

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this up, it ended up being that the boxes were connecting with their internal ips within the replica set, but I was trying to connect via their external ips. They need to match up.